# Intellij IDEA - Identifying all junit tests which are ignored

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit4

Can someone let me know is there a way I can identify all JUnit tests which are ignored i.e either `@Ignore` being added to the method or `@Test` is missing on the method in IntelliJ IDEA?

- IDEA Version - 2017.2.2
- JUnit - 4.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding test classes which contain the `@Ignore` annotation can be done with `Edit > Find > Find in Path` ...

[image]

Finding test classes where "@Test is missing on the method" is trickier because any class can be a test class. Or to put it another way; a class is deemed a "test class" if (a) it is located in the test source tree and (b) it has at least one public method annotated with `@Test`. So, the absence of `@Test` would preclude a class from your search. So, perhaps you are looking for classes which meet these criteria:

- Having at least one method annotated with `@Test`
- Having at least one public method which is not annotated with `@Test`

This would require a [Structural Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html), accessed from `Edit > Find > Search Structurally`. There are numerous canned templates available:

[image]